# Why is my Broadband Dongle not detected after upgrade to 13.04?

Tags: network-manager, 13.04, mobile-broadband

I got a strange problem! My broadband dongle is not being detected on my Dell 5220 laptop after I updated to Ubuntu 13.04. Previously it was working fine in 12.10.

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found a solution ,

installed this on my laptop. now i can connect via this application pretty cool.

http://dokter-internet-indonesia.blogspot.com/2013/05/mobile-partner-linux-bam-huawei.html

**EDIT**

If above link is not working, **Google** for Mobile Partner Linux (BAM Huawei) 21.003.28.00.03 and get download and install

this is my solution if any one have another solution please post

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: i have already added a link here! i just installed that application and connected my huwai dongal

Comment: @JamesMuscat i could not guaranteed the links that were on web .. even btw i have updated answer..